# fitting a multivariate polynomial to 3D data

Tags: mathematical-modeling, multivariate-polynomial

I collected data about the response function, $f$, for each and every combination of three parameters $x$, $y$ and $\theta$, that represent horizontal position, vertical position and orientation, respectively. The data is shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvOVo.png), sliced at discrete values of $\theta=30,60,...,360$.

It can be clearly seen that higher response varies radially as $\theta$ changes. My first attempt to model this 3D response function, I considered the following linear model: 
$$f(x, y, \theta)=\alpha_0+\alpha_x \cdot x+\alpha_y \cdot y + \alpha_\theta \cdot \theta$$
The result (using standard least squares optimization methods in Matlab) is shown on [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qEfU.png).

After looking at the result I realized that my model (which represents a hyperplane?) is wrong. However, I can't seem to come up with any other justified model. If a multivariate polynomial can be fitted to the data above, how should it look like?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are linear with respect to each parameter, then the equation of the generalized linear model should be
$$f(x, y, \theta)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 y + a_3 \theta+a_4 x y+ a_5 x \theta+a_6 y \theta+a_7 x y\theta$$